# Repeated Combinations Reasoning

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose I have 3 types of flowers and I want to have 2 flowers.

Shouldn't the answer be $(3 * 3)/2!$ as I have 3 ways to select 1st flower, 3 for 3nd flower and as I don't care about order, I divide by $2!$.

But the answer here will comee out to be 4.5 which is not possible.

Where is my reasoning wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't divide by $2$. The reason to divide by $2$ is to prevent double counting. If I have types of flowers $a,b,c$, I get $3*3=9$ possible ordered pairs. But some of those pairs are NOT double counting (for example, the pair $(a,a)$ is not double counted). Therefore dividing everything by $2$ is not the right thing to do, since some of the terms are not double counted in the first place.

Comment: In your $3*3=9$ terms, you have three terms ($(a,a)$, $(b,b)$, $(c,c)$) which are not double counted, and the other six are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is only one way of choosing the first type of flower $f_1$ twice, and similarly for $f_2$ and $f_3$. On the other hand, you can choose different flowers, e.g. flower 1 and flower 2, in two distinct ways, namely $(f_1,f_2)$ and $(f_2,f_1)$. You could count the number $N$ of different combinations as follows instead: Choosing the same flower twice can be done in one way, and choosing any two different flowers can be done in two ways (which you want to consider as the same way, hence the factor $\tfrac12$ below), so

\begin{align*}
N = 3\cdot 1 + 2\cdot{{3}\choose{2}}\cdot\frac12 = 6.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Because in your reasoning, we can also choose the first flower twice, or the second flower twice, or the third flower twice. So there are $3$ cases which are not overcounted.